# Use of scale_x_discrete in R ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a problem using the discrete scale in ggplot2 in R. The use of

```
g + scale_x_discrete(breaks=1:7, labels=1:7)
```

incorrectly changes in limits of a plot.

Before:

[image: before]

After:
[image]

I cannot see anything suspicious about the code I use to produce the image, but here is it:

```
g <- ggplot(data=plottingData, aes(x=x, y=y, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", fill=col) +
geom_errorbar(width=0.5*binwidth, size=0.3)
```

Comment: Could you upload `dput` again? I have been receiving error messages. It seems to me that you got dput for a ggplot object. Could you upload dput of your data?

Comment: @jazzurro: Yes, this is the ggplot2 object - I thought this was easier to work with rather than having to give the plottingData (which actually contains some irrelevant stuff) as well as the col and binwidth. shadow's answer below solved the problem for me.

Comment: I removed the dput() as it was unusable

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That probably already happens when you add `g + scale_x_discrete()`. This happens when using a discrete scale for continuous data. Without the breaks, you can see the wrong limits and just change them.

```
g + scale_x_discrete()
g + scale_x_discrete(limits=1:7)
g + scale_x_discrete(limits=1:7, labels = letters[1:7])
```

Alternatively, you can use `factor` to get the proper limits from the beginning. Of course you'll have to rename the axis.

```
ggplot(data=plottingData, aes(x=factor(x), y=y, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill=col) +
  geom_errorbar(width=0.5*binwidth, size=0.3) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = 'x')
```

Answer (score 5):

```
p1 + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2, 4, 6))
```