# How to collapse my x-axis to represent discrete values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've run the following code and get the graph as provided here.
Since the x-axis represents sampling locations I want to the gaps on the x-axis representing values which are irrelevant

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=SU,fill=factor(SCIENTIFIC_NAME)))+
  geom_bar(width=0.5)+xlab("Sampling Unit (SU)")+
  ylab("Count")+labs(fill="SCIENTIFIC NAME")+
  ggtitle("Inventory per Sampling Unit (SU) by species")+ 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,15))
```

[image: Inventory count per sampling unit based on species]

Comment: Try to make your question [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), it's going to be easier to help you.

Comment: can you please give input data to the plot by copying to you post the result of dput(dat)

Comment: Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28742870/use-of-scale-x-discrete-in-r-ggplot2)

Comment: This is a guess, but probably `aes(x=as.factor(SU), ...)` would solve the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of scale\_x\_discrete in R ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28742870/use-of-scale-x-discrete-in-r-ggplot2)

Comment: The combination of the MarBlo and Waldi comments solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use a discrete scale instead of a continuous scale and make sure the x-axis is a factor:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=factor(SU),fill=factor(SCIENTIFIC_NAME)))+
  geom_bar(width=0.5)+xlab("Sampling Unit (SU)")+
  ylab("Count")+labs(fill="SCIENTIFIC NAME")+
  ggtitle("Inventory per Sampling Unit (SU) by species")+ 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,15))
```

Answer (score 2):

you should make the *SU* a factor `aes(x=factor(SU),fill=factor(SCIENTIFIC_NAME))`