# EDIT: How to convert to factor variable to order Time data on plot

Tags: r, variables, ggplot2

EDIT ::: I would like the values on the X axis to by in chronological order in AM and PM groups. so 1:00AM - 11:00AM 12:00PM - 9:00PM

I know this has to do with changing my ActivityHoursII variable to a factor. However I am unsure on the steps to do this.

currently:
factorintensities <- factor(hourlyIntensitiesclean$ActivityHour)
levels(factorintensities)
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwbdv.png) "4/12/2016 1:00:00 AM"  "4/12/2016 1:00:00 PM"  "4/12/2016 10:00:00 AM" "4/12/2016 10:00:00 PM"
[5] "4/12/2016 11:00:00 AM" "4/12/2016 11:00:00 PM" "4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM" "4/12/2016 12:00:00 PM"
[9] "4/12/2016 2:00:00 AM"  "4/12/2016 2:00:00 PM"  "4/12/2016 3:00:00 AM"  "4/12/2016 3:00:00 PM"
[13] "4/12/2016 4:00:00 AM"  "4/12/2016 4:00:00 PM"  "4/12/2016 5:00:00 AM"  "4/12/2016 5:00:00 PM"
[17] "4/12/2016 6:00:00 AM"  "4/12/2016 6:00:00 PM"  "4/12/2016 7:00:00 AM"  "4/12/2016 7:00:00 PM"
[21] "4/12/2016 8:00:00 AM"  "4/12/2016 8:00:00 PM"  "4/12/2016 9:00:00 AM"  "4/12/2016 9:00:00 PM"

I would like there to be only two levels.. all data for AM and all data for PM. This function does not work

factorintensities <- factor(hourlyIntensitiesclean$ActivityHour, levels = "AM", "PM")

Here is my code for graph

```
ggplot(data=hourlyIntensities_mergedclean) +
geom_point(mapping = aes(x = ActivityHoursII, y = AverageIntensity)) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45))
```

dplot

```
structure(list(Id = c("user_1", "user_1", "user_1", "user_1", 
"user_1", "user_1", "user_1", "user_1", "user_1", "user_1"), 
ActivityHour = c("4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 1:00:00 AM", 
"4/12/2016 2:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 3:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 4:00:00 AM", 
"4/12/2016 5:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 6:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 7:00:00 AM", 
"4/12/2016 8:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 9:00:00 AM"), TotalIntensity = c(20, 
8, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 30), AverageIntensity = c(0.333333, 
0.133333, 0.116667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.216667, 0.5), ActivityHouredit = c("12:00:00 AM", 
"1:00:00 AM", "2:00:00 AM", "3:00:00 AM", "4:00:00 AM", "5:00:00 AM", 
"6:00:00 AM", "7:00:00 AM", "8:00:00 AM", "9:00:00 AM"), 
ActivityHoursII = c("12:00:00 AM", "1:00:00 AM", "2:00:00 AM", 
"3:00:00 AM", "4:00:00 AM", "5:00:00 AM", "6:00:00 AM", "7:00:00 AM", 
"8:00:00 AM", "9:00:00 AM")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have only a single day?

Comment: Perhaps, you want `hourlyIntensities_mergedclean$ActivityHoursII <- factor(hourlyIntensities_mergedclean$ActivityHoursII, levels = unique(gtools::mixedsort(hourlyIntensities_mergedclean$ActivityHoursII)))`

Comment: give levels to the factor columns or use `scale_x_discrete()` to specify the axis order. Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28742870/use-of-scale-x-discrete-in-r-ggplot2)

Comment: @DennyChen this is my question, I am unsure of how to give levels to the factor column

Comment: @akrun that did not work

Comment: @Stackstudent_09 your example didn't had the `PM` values.  So, I couldn't test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `df` be the name of the data.

**METHOD 1**

We can specify the order of the axis first.

```
axisorder <- c("1:00:00 AM","2:00:00 AM","3:00:00 AM","4:00:00 AM","5:00:00 AM","6:00:00 AM","7:00:00 AM", "8:00:00 AM", "9:00:00 AM", "12:00:00 AM")
```

And then use `limits` argument in `scale_x_discrete` function to reorder the axis.

```
ggplot(data=df) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = ActivityHoursII, y = AverageIntensity)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = axisorder)
```

**METHOD 2**

OR, we can change the column into factor and give it levels.

```
df$ActivityHoursII <- factor(df$ActivityHoursII, levels = axisorder)
```

And then plot it without `scale_x_discrete`

```
ggplot(data=df) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = ActivityHoursII, y = AverageIntensity)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45))
```

And we can get the plot :

[image: desire plot]